# I need to move and rotate view around point in the screen with pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiview, uikit

I want to make the view rotate and move around the center of the screen.

Here is visual representation of what I want to achieve. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8YPQ.png)

And my current solution:

```
@objc func circleMoved(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .changed:
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
    
        circle.layer.zPosition = 200
        let spread = view.width
        let angle: CGFloat = 100
        
        let angleMoveX = angle * translation.x / spread
        let angleMoveY = angle * translation.y / spread
        
        let angleMoveXRadians = angleMoveX * CGFloat.pi/180
        let angleMoveYRadians = angleMoveY * CGFloat.pi/180
        
        var move = CATransform3DIdentity
        move = CATransform3DRotate(move, angleMoveXRadians, 0, 1, 0)
        move = CATransform3DRotate(move, -angleMoveYRadians, 1, 0, 0)
        move = CATransform3DTranslate(move, translation.x, translation.y, 0)
        
        circle.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(circle.layer.transform, move)
    
    
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)  } }
```

But the problem is that it rotates more than I wanted. (60 degrees max)

Comment: Unclear what the issue is. If you don't want to be able to rotate more than a certain amount, clamp to that amount.

Comment: Question is - how to limit to that angle? It has to move but angle should stay maximum if it goes beyond limit.